# How to fill a pandas dataframe from two 2d numpy arrays in an efficient way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = [ "S" + str(i) for i in range(1,101)]
c = [ "C" + str(i) for i in range(1,51)]

arr1 = np.random.randn(len(c),len(s))
arr2 = np.random.randn(len(c),len(s))
```

How to create and fill pandas dataframe df with 100 * 50 = 5000 rows for each possible s and c pairs
such that **arr1_col** has **arr1[s,c]** and
**arr2_col** has **arr2[s,c]**?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'S':s, 'C':c, 'arr1_col':arr1[s,c] ,  'arr2_col':arr2[s,c]})
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] with a 5x6 shape and the explicit expected output? Use `np.random.seed(0)` after imports for reproducibility.

Comment: Didn't you invert `c` and `s` in `np.random.randn(len(c),len(s))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this 4x3 reproducible input:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = [ "S" + str(i) for i in range(1,4+1)]
c = [ "C" + str(i) for i in range(1,3+1)]

arr1 = np.arange(len(c)*len(s)).reshape(len(s), len(c))
arr2 = np.arange(len(c)*len(s)).reshape(len(s), len(c))*10
```

I imagine that you want to use [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html), [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) and [`numpy.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
# numpy_1
df = pd.DataFrame({'S': np.repeat(s, len(c)),
                   'C': np.tile(c, len(s)),
                   'arr1': arr1.ravel(),
                   'arr2': arr2.ravel(),
                  })
```

Or with [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
# pandas_1
df = (pd.concat({'arr1': pd.DataFrame(arr1, index=s, columns=c),
                 'arr2': pd.DataFrame(arr2, index=s, columns=c),},
                axis=1)
        .stack().rename_axis(['S', 'C']).reset_index()
     )
```

Output:

```
     S   C  arr1  arr2
0   S1  C1     0     0
1   S1  C2     1    10
2   S1  C3     2    20
3   S2  C1     3    30
4   S2  C2     4    40
5   S2  C3     5    50
6   S3  C1     6    60
7   S3  C2     7    70
8   S3  C3     8    80
9   S4  C1     9    90
10  S4  C2    10   100
11  S4  C3    11   110
```

---

###### ordering C first

```
# numpy_2
df = pd.DataFrame({'S': np.tile(s, len(c)),
                   'C': np.repeat(c, len(s)),
                   'arr1': arr1.ravel(order='F'),
                   'arr2': arr2.ravel(order='F'),
                  })
```

Or:

```
# pandas_2
df = (pd.concat({'arr1': pd.DataFrame(arr1, index=s, columns=c),
                 'arr2': pd.DataFrame(arr2, index=s, columns=c),},
                axis=0)
        .T.stack().rename_axis(['C', 'S']).reset_index()
     )
```

Output:

```
     S   C  arr1  arr2
0   S1  C1     0     0
1   S2  C1     3    30
2   S3  C1     6    60
3   S4  C1     9    90
4   S1  C2     1    10
5   S2  C2     4    40
6   S3  C2     7    70
7   S4  C2    10   100
8   S1  C3     2    20
9   S2  C3     5    50
10  S3  C3     8    80
11  S4  C3    11   110
```

---

##### comparison of timings

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @mozway. Stunned by for solutions while the first solution is easier to understand.  Can you explain the solution with the stack?  Which solution is more efficient?

Comment: The `stack` approach starts with 2D pandas structures and flattens them. Check the output of `pd.DataFrame(arr1, index=s, columns=c)` and `pd.DataFrame(arr1, index=s, columns=c).stack()`. I haven't timed the solutions but I'd expect the numpy ones to be faster.

Comment: Thanks mozway. For my question, C as rows  and S as columns,  df = pd.DataFrame({'S': np.tile(s, len(c)),
                   'C': np.repeat(c, len(s)),
                   'arr1': arr1.ravel(),
                   'arr2': arr2.ravel(),
                  })  changing 'tile' and 'repeat' would work correctly.

Comment: I added a comparison of timings. Numpy is faster until a threshold, then pandas catches up and is a bit faster. I only tested for square inputs, this might vary if the shape is uneven.

Comment: Looks about the same if the shape is uneven. The threshold is a bit different (but the total size is not directly comparable).